# Hide no image found icon on ie (SVG)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, svg

I've seen a few questions about hiding the no image found icon on IE for images but not for svg's. Basically, my svg looks like:

```
<image id="svg_full" xlink:href="" y="66" width="600" height="862"/>
```

Then `onClick` I add the href attribute to point to an image depending on what I click.

Works fine however, on IE I get the no image found symbol and an outline of the image.

Is there anyway I can remove this?

Thanks!

EDIT:

I did what Robert suggested, thanks! My `svg` now looks like:

```
<image id="svg_full" xlink:href="" y="66" width="0" height="862"/>
```

Then `onClick` I just toggle the width to display my `svg`:

```
$('#svg_full').attr('width', '0px');
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set the width and height to 0 until you load the image. If the image has no size then IE can't display the no image found symbol.